# Perform auto-search in ionic with MongoDB as backend

Tags: mongodb, ionic-framework, ionic-view

The search should be based on the first name and last name. During entering the letters the middle letters from the word should not come. It should come only only from the first name and last name. I got the auto-complete code from code pen and Github but as per requirement I need auto search;

Like:

[Auto Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD7Rc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at creating your own custom directive or using an existing one like this https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

This is my code snippet for auto-complete which I used but I need First name and last name Search (It should not search random letters) -

var airlines = [{"fs":"LCI","iata":"LF","icao":"LCI","name":"Lao Central Airlines ","active":true},{"fs":"TGU","iata":"5U","icao":"TGU","name":"TAG","active":true},{"fs":"BT","iata":"BT","icao":"BTI","name":"Air Baltic","active":true},{"fs":"9J","iata":"9J","icao":"DAN","name":"Dana Airlines","active":true},{"fs":"2O","iata":"2O","icao":"RNE","name":"Island Air Service","active":true},{"fs":"NPT","icao":"NPT","name":"Atlantic Airlines","active":true},{"fs":"C8","iata":"C8","icao":"ICV","name":"Cargolux Italia","active":true},{"fs":"FK","iata":"FK","icao":"WTA","name":"Africa West","active":true},{"fs":"8K","iata":"8K","icao":"EVS","name":"EVAS Air Charters","active":true},{"fs":"W8","iata":"W8","icao":"CJT","name":"Cargojet","active":true},{"fs":"JBW","iata":"3J","icao":"JBW","name":"Jubba Airways (Kenya)","active":true},{"fs":"TNU","iata":"M8","icao":"TNU","name":"TransNusa","active":true},{"fs":"HCC","iata":"HC","icao":"HCC","name":"Holidays Czech Airlines","active":true},{"fs":"APJ","iata":"MM","icao":"APJ","name":"Peach Aviation","active":true},{"fs":"TUY","iata":"L4","icao":"TUY","name":"LTA","active":true},{"fs":"LAE","iata":"L7","icao":"LAE","name":"LANCO","active":true},{"fs":"L5*","iata":"L5","icao":"LTR","name":"Lufttransport","active":true},{"fs":"QA","iata":"QA","icao":"CIM","name":"Cimber","active":true},{"fs":"KBZ","iata":"K7","icao":"KBZ","name":"Air KBZ","active":true},{"fs":"L2","iata":"L2","icao":"LYC","name":"Lynden Air Cargo","active":true},{"fs":"MPK","iata":"I6","icao":"MPK","name":"Air Indus","active":true},{"fs":"CAO","icao":"CAO","name":"Air China Cargo ","active":true},{"fs":"BEK","iata":"Z9","icao":"BEK","name":"Bek Air","active":true},{"fs":"IAE","iata":"IO","icao":"IAE","name":"IrAero","active":true},{"fs":"GL*","iata":"GL","name":"Airglow Aviation Services","active":true},{"fs":"ATN","iata":"8C","icao":"ATN","name":"ATI","active":true},{"fs":"GU","iata":"GU","icao":"GUG","name":"Aviateca Guatemala","active":true},{"fs":"GHY","icao":"GHY","name":"German Sky Airlines ","active":true},{"fs":"SS","iata":"SS","icao":"CRL","name":"Corsair","active":true},{"fs":"XK","iata":"XK","icao":"CCM","name":"Air Corsica","active":true},{"fs":"W9*","iata":"W9","icao":"JAB","name":"Air Bagan","active":true},{"fs":"Z8*","iata":"Z8","icao":"AZN","name":"Amaszonas","active":true},{"fs":"D2","iata":"D2","icao":"SSF","name":"Severstal Aircompany","active":true},{"fs":"SNC","iata":"2Q","icao":"SNC","name":"Air Cargo Carriers","active":true},{"fs":"PST","iata":"7P","icao":"PST","name":"Air Panama","active":true},{"fs":"VV","iata":"VV","icao":"AEW","name":"Aerosvit Airlines","active":true},{"fs":"UJ","iata":"UJ","icao":"LMU","name":"AlMasria","active":true},{"fs":"9U","iata":"9U","icao":"MLD","name":"Air Moldova","active":true},{"fs":"NF","iata":"NF","icao":"AVN","name":"Air Vanuatu","phoneNumber":"678 238 48","active":true},{"fs":"NJS","iata":"NC","icao":"NJS","name":"Cobham Aviation","active":true}];

airlines = airlines.sort(function(a, b) {

```
var airlineA = a.name.to();
var airlineB = b.name.toLowerCase();

if(airlineA > airlineB) return 1;
if(airlineA < airlineB) return -1;
return 0;
```

});

console.log(airlines);

angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.factory('FlightDataService', function($q, $timeout) {

```
var searchAirlines = function(searchFilter) {

    console.log('Searching airlines for ' + searchFilter);

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var matches = airlines.filter( function(airline) {
        if(airline.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFilter.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ) return true;
    })

    $timeout( function(){

       deferred.resolve( matches );

    }, 100);

    return deferred.promise;

};

return {

    searchAirlines : searchAirlines

}
```

})

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'FlightDataService', function($scope, FlightDataService) {

```
$scope.myTitle = 'Auto Complete Example';

$scope.data = { "airlines" : [], "search" : '' };

$scope.search = function() {

    FlightDataService.searchAirlines($scope.data.search).then(
        function(matches) {
            $scope.data.airlines = matches;
        }
    )
}
```

}]);